# Erro na função __toString PHP7

Tags: php

Qual a solução para o erro abaixo?

```
public function __toString(){

        return json_encode(array(

            "idusuario"   =>$this->getIdusuario(),
            "deslogin"    =>$this->getDeslogin(),
            "dessenha"    =>$this->getDessenha(),
            "tdcadastro"  =>$this->getDtcadastro()->format("d/m/Y - H: i: s")

        ));

}
```

Este é o erro:

> Fatal error: Method Usuario::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function format() on null in

Comment: O erro não é no método `__toString`. Qual instância `getDtcadastro` retorna? Se possível ponha o código também.

Comment: Pelo jeito vc tem um `new throw execption()` ou alguma instrução lançou uma exception aí

Comment: Parece que a data do teu cadastro tá com valor null e o método format não consegue formatar sua data a partir de null.

Answer (score 1):

O Erro

> Fatal error: Method Usuario::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function format() on null in

Está ocorrendo justamente porque `$this->getDtcadastro()` **é *nulo* (`null`)** e também antes de dar o `return` e o `json_encode` dê um `print_r` no seu *array* e verifique se não está vazio.